# Why there will be a baseline for LSTM and how to improve the performance?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a LSTM network with the following configuration:

```
model3 = tf.keras.Sequential()
model3.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(15, input_shape=(1, 10), return_sequences=True)) 
model3.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(5))
model3.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=None))
model3.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model3.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=30)
```

The result can predict the tendency but there will be a stable baseline, which is abnormal. The figure is like the following:

[image: prediction results]

So I wonder why there is a stable line even if there is no activation function in my last layer. And also how to improve performance.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean by a "stable line" please?

Comment: @DavidParks I think it means the red curve has a noise level around 1000, looks like a straight line

Comment: @MiloLu is correct. For example, the line between 1500 and 2000 for x. The prediction is nearly a straight line without any fluctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two quite small LSTM layers to predict for what I assume is limited data. The relationship learned between the input and output will therefore be quite basic (as opposed to a deep model).

In regards to your question, you must analyze the outputs according to your cost function. Using a cost function such as MSE will penalize the model for having large discrepancies between the output and true values, and it appears that what the model has learned here is that the value (around 900) is the value which minimizes MSE using the small amount of parameters available. So is this "abnormal" as you described? I would say it was abnormal if the line did not appear to almost be a line of best fit throughout the lower values of the data.

What I would suggest to you is using a simpler network if your training data is not sufficient (see possibly CNNs, or windowed ANNs), or seeing if it is possible to obtain more training data.

Comment: Thanks. But why the baseline (around 900) is stable through the whole test set?  It can be a declining line but it shows horizontal. Is that because the model is too simple?

Comment: I would even take a guess the mean of your training data is around that 900 line. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes the mean is around 970. So the model is using mean value to fit the values which model cannot determine, right?

Comment: Because your model is so small (15 nodes then 5 nodes) it is severely underfitting your data. I think the fact that it predicts some of the peaks in your graph provided is encouraging as it is learning some possibly obvious traits in the data. What the model has learned is that a default value of ~900 is the value which allows it to minimise the MSE. I would try either a) Increasing the size of your model (100 nodes, single layer, maybe?) or b) using a simpler architecture (basic RNN, windowed ANN). LSTMs are very data hungry, but do very well when they do have that data available.

Comment: Does the number of layers affect the model? Why do you suggest one layer instead of multiple layers?

Comment: Yes, each added layer will add complexity to the model. If you have a small dataset and are unsure if LSTMs will work, starting with one layer is a good way to gauge initial performance.